# отрисовка background

Tags: java, android, libgdx

я пишу программу и в какой-то момент у меня была одна текстура, но потом пришлось разделить ее на 2 разные части (пополам) и, соответственно, отрисовывать через два batch.draw (тогда я сделал два разных метода для этого) и сейчас мне нужно отказаться от двух разных текстур в пользу одной, использовал старую картинку, убрал второй, добавочный метод, но получил лишь белый прямоугольник в верхней правой части, от камеры, такое чувство, что они привязаны почему-то друг к другу

```
render() {

    batch.begin();
    background.drawBackground(batch); //рисовка фона
    background.drawUpMenu(batch, camera); //рисовка меню
    background.drawUpActivity(batch); //активная зона
    batch.end();
}



void drawBackground(Batch batch) { //рисовка фона
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0);
}

void drawUpMenu(Batch batch, Camera camera) { //рисовка меню
    batch.draw(upMenu, camera.position.x - (WIDTH / 2), camera.position.y - (HEIGHT / 2));
}

void drawUpActivity(Batch batch) {она нужна
        batch.draw(upActivity, 10, 70);
}
```

если убрать drawUpActivity() в render, то появится этот белый прямоугольник, хотя сейчас текстурой upActivity является пара пикселей розового цвета :/

код работает и так, но я хочу это убрать, спасибо

Comment: я действительно не знаю в чем может быть проблема